# laravel relationship between 3 tables - many-to-many

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I have 3 tables (Models)

```
Advertise :
    id
    title
    ...

Value:
    id
    title
    amount
    ....

Field:
    id
    name
    title
    ...

and my pivot tables is like:
    advertise_id
    value_id
    field_id
```

how can I set relations in my models and do a crud(please give me an example)?
all the relations are many to many

Comment: _how can I set relations in my models and do a crud(please give me an example)_ Read the Laravel **docs**, it's literally in there!

Comment: What do you mean by all the relations are many to many? Is that mean `Advertise` many-to-many `Field`, `Advertise` many-to-many `Value` and `Field` many-to-many `Value`?

Answer (score 0):

3 model classes accordingly:

```
class Advertise extends Model
{
    public function fields()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Field::class);
    }

    public function values()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Value::class);
    }
}

class Field extends Model
{
    public function advertises()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Advertise::class);
    }

    public function values()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Value::class);
    }
}

class Value extends Model
{
    public function fields()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Field::class);
    }

    public function advertises()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Advertise::class);
    }
}
```